# Need to list each file name in node before results of the function

Tags: node.js, recursion

Im using node to check through a directory tree and tell me all of the empty values in a set of JSON files. The following code, however, is returning the file path list and then the results of the function. I want each filename to precede its results so:

Filename

result

result

Filename

result...

```
var glob = require("glob"),
fs = require('fs');


glob("**/*/locales/*/*.json", function (er, files) {
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++  ){

        console.log(files[i]);

        fs.readFile(files[i], 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }

                var local = JSON.parse(data);
                checkStr(local);
        });

    }
});

function checkStr (obj, parent) {
    var parent = parent || "";
    if (parent.length > 0) {parent = parent + '.'}
    for(key in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[key]) === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            checkStr(obj[key], key);
        }
        else {
            if(!obj[key].valueOf()){
                console.log( "This is empty: " + parent + key );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you store the results in an array and then log that out in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var glob = require('glob');
var fs = require('fs');

function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
    for (var name in obj) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function findEmptyKey(parent, obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            if (isObjectEmpty(obj[key])) {
                result.push(parent + '\\' + key);
            } else {
                Array.prototype.push.apply(result, findEmptyKey(key, obj[key]));
            }
        } else if (!obj[key]) {
            result.push(parent + '\\' + key);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function processFile(file) {

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        var keys = findEmptyKey('', JSON.parse(data));
        if (keys.length>0) {
            console.log(file);
            keys.forEach(function(key) { console.log('This is empty: ' + key); });
        }
    });
}

glob("**/*/locales/*/*.json", function (er, files) {
    files.forEach(processFile);
});
```